How does ASP.NET verify a JWT?
We are using JWT bearer authentication:
var cognitoIssuer = "https://cognito-idp.someRegion.amazonaws.com/someUserPoolId";
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = cognitoIssuer;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    });

I'm trying to work out where in the sourcecode, ASP.NET verifies the incoming JWT.
I searched for ".well-known/openid-configuration" on GitHub and found this:
options.MetadataAddress += ".well-known/openid-configuration";

I assumed MetadataAddress would be read somewhere to make an HTTP request in order to get the public key from the IdP in order to verify the JWT's signature.
But I can't find anywhere where MetadataAddress is being read.
Where is the section of code that gets the public key and verifies the JWT's signature?
